# Flutter send notification regularly on particular time

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications

I want send user notification regularly like everyday at morning and at night, and on every Sunday night, every Monday morning, also may be on festivals automatically even if user is not using the app and it is in background. How to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/) to send Push Notifications. Setup a backend for that and there you can create a `cron job` to get you desired time interval to send notifications.

Comment: Please share if there is any documentation related to this, and what backend do I use, and how? What is cron job, Please can you explain in detail am new to flutter.

Comment: Everything about Push Notifications is explained in [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/). Also the Server side of that is explained there. Just have a look on it.

Comment: You can check out a [JavaScript Cron Job](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

Comment: Also checkout this here https://crontab.guru/

Comment: ok thank u lemme check